# getting 'backup not found' on heroku pgbackups

Tags: heroku, backup, restore, pg

I want to restore the backup from staging to demo

I followed the documentation on heroku and combed through SO but no luck so far.

I am using Windows 7 and versions are:

heroku/toolbelt/2.33.2 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.2
Ruby: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]
Rails: 3.2.7

Steps:

```
$heroku pgbackups:capture

HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ONYX_URL (DATABASE_URL)  ----backup--->  b004

←[0KCapturing... donet |
←[0KStoring... done

$heroku pgbackups:url
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/hkpgbackups........."
```

I know the command above is not required but I did it anyway just to make sure that a url is generated for backup db.

and the command for restore:

```
$heroku pgbackups:restore --remote demo DATABASE 'heroku pgbackups:url'

 **!    Backup not found**
```

Just to be sure, I tried the following other formats of the command:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore --remote demo DATABASE 'heroku pgbackups:url --remote staging'

heroku pgbackups:restore --app demoapp DATABASE 'heroku pgbackups:url --app stagingapp'
```

They both are resulting in Backup not found error

I also tried with the name of the db on demo:

```
$heroku pgbackups:restore HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE 'heroku pgbackups:url --remote staging' --remote demo
 !    Backup not found
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Use backquotes instead of single quotes.

`` `  heroku pgbackups:url -a source-app `` `

Answer (score 0):

Log into your heroku control panel and make sure the version of PGbackup you have isn't depreciated